# codeigniter redirects and search engine bots

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, search-engine

I am new to codeigniter. In fact, I'm not even working on it. I'm just employed to work the SEO for a website. I only have access to the cpanel of the site, not the dashboard of the codeigniter (I wonder if there is one?)

So far I have been able to figure out everything that needs my attention. Only problem now is the search bots seems to be hitting redirects. When I tried to fetch as Bingbot, I get the following

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 12 Jun 2016 00:34:29 GMT
Content-Length: 234
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: http://www.domain.com/
Server: Apache



<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.domain.com/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

I figured it might be the redirect rules written into the .htaccess. But I really don't know what to change to allow for the bot to smoothly crawl the site. View .htaccess below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What do I need to add to the .htaccess file to allow search engines crawl the site without hitting to http 301 again? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you put this code in .htaccess file?

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I didn't develop the site. Another dev did. I was only asked by the site owner to optimize it for search engines. The reason for the redirect codes is bcos the site is on files are in subdirectory. While the main .htaccess file redirects to the /public directory, the above code is what is in the .htaccess file of /public. I'm just hoping I could get help in modifying the redirect instructions to allow search engines crawl without altering stuffs on the site.